# Update App Service configuration settings with PowerShell for all App Services in a Resource Group

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

How do I update the configuration settings with PowerShell for all App Services in the Resource Group? Alternatively, is there an option in Azure DevOps, or using other tools, to update web application settings?

Comment: It’s certainly possible to write an [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-3.6.1) script which will loop through every App Service and apply a setting to each. That said, Microsoft _also_ offers the [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview), which allows applications to share a single, centralized set of configuration settings.

Comment: @muralid Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Alternatively, is there an option in Azure DevOps, or using other
>   tools, to update web application settings?

For this issue , you can update the configuration in the `Application and Configuration Settings` area in the [Azure App Service deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) task. Here is a [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/654827/release-pipeline-step-azure-app-service-deployment.html) you can refer to.

- **AppSettings**: Edit web app Application settings using the syntax
  **-key value**. Values containing spaces must be enclosed in double quotes. Examples: -Port 5000 -RequestTimeout 5000.
- **ConfigurationSettings**: Edit web app configuration settings using the
  syntax **-key value**. Values containing spaces must be enclosed in
  double quotes. Example: -phpVersion 5.6 -linuxFxVersion: node|6.11.

[image]

In addition , you can try [Azure App Service Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-settings?view=azure-devops) task. Using this task to configure App settings, connection strings and other general settings in bulk using JSON syntax on your web app or any of its deployment slots.